# How to detect/monitor AC power

Tags: ac, detector

I'm attempting to build a system to help my Father-in-law monitor the power to his house.  Here's the details of his problem: He lives in the woods where power is somewhat unreliable so he has a whole house generator.  He travels frequently and he'd like a system to let him know when he's **A)** lost external power to the house **B)** lost external power and is on generator power and **C)** lost generator power.

My current solution which detects **B** and **C**: an arduino Uno with a Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 and a Adafruit Fona 808.  The PowerBoost is connected to an outlet with on Generator power, so I can monitor whether my device has AC power and whether it's on battery power.  I use the Fona for notification via SMS.

My initial configuration to detect **A** was to put a simple 5VDC A/C Adapter into an outlet that wasn't on the Generator circuit and have that power a relay.  If the relay contact is closed, I have external AC power.  I'm concerned about the reliability of a relay being closed for several days/months/years at a time... is my concern valid?  Is there a simple/more elegant solution to this part?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a few mA through the contact, and it is a signal type with sealed contacts it should be reliable. I'm not a big fan of reed relays.

You could also use an optoisolator rather than a relay. You'd need a couple resistors (for the input and a pullup on the output).

There are also [modules](http://www.grayhill.com/assets/1/7/IO_Mod_AC_Input.pdf) made to accept an AC input and provide a logic level output, probably $15 or so. That would get rid of the adapter and the relay (Photo from Digikey).

[image]